# MSSQL 2008 License for both Web application and desktop application

Tags: windows-server-2008, licensing, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I have ASP.NET web application using MSSQL express at the moment. But I want to use MSSQL 2008. But I'm NOT sure
about what kind of license I should buy. I'm considering the Processor License according to [this documen](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/e/6/1e68f92c-f334-4517-b610-e4dee946ef91/2008%20SQL%20Licensing%20overview%20final.docx)t.
I'm not sure if it's the right choice.

If I buy User CAL. should I buy only 1 CAL for my web application? or for all visitors who visit my web site?

I also have a Windows desktop application that write/read data from the server. Do I need a seperate license with
for this Windows application if I buy Processor License.

Thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

For a web-app, a per-processor license is by far the least ambiguous. It allows the maximum flexibility without worry of blowing over your CAL limit.

Answer (score 0):

SPLA. Go for SPLA and rent the softwar emonthly. A lot cheaper than puchasing. No CAL allowed - and, btwl, you would need one per visitor, not just one.

But then, normal licensing is not good for web apps, which is why there is SPLA (Service Provider Licensing Agreement).